# Young Adult book about kids being bred for genetic purity in a world where races no longer exist

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, genetics

I'm looking for a book I read in Junior High (probably) about a world where everyone was basically the same race.  One genetically pure male and female teenager of each race still exists.  They are transporting a genetically pure boy to meet his genetically pure female counterpart and accidentally introduce him to a genetically pure female of a different race.  And, of course, chaos ensues.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What language was it written in?  When did you read it (we don't know when you were in junior high)?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214154/story-about-a-future-with-races (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 11):

Pretty sure that is Piers Anthony's [Race against Time](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15505.Race_Against_Time) (1973).

Some details to help verify:

- He lives in a town which is done to LOOK like Nebraska, but isn't.
- He has a dog that seems to have capabilities beyond what a dog should have.
- Adults are actually a medium color, but spray themselves to appear Caucasian (in his area.  Different colors are used in the other areas.)
- The various kids all eventually meet up and flee the planet.

Sound about right?

Comment: Yes, that is it!!  Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @MrsDizzyChester - Glad I could help -- don't forget to hit 'accept' if it's the correct answer, or it will remain a pending question :)